# Unity Tweak Tool - Schema missing

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

I installed unity tweak tool through the terminal and whenever i try to run it I get the dialog "the following schema is missing: com.canonical.indicator.bluetooth. I tried to look online for solutions but it was mostly people who had different type of schemas missing. I even installed the packages they recommended but it didn't do anything. I anybody knows how to solve this particular problem it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What version Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install indicator-bluetooth
```

You need source universe.

Comment: I did that but then it keeps giving me different errors. I install one and then it says there is another missing

Comment: The errors are a secret? :D  Please post them by eding you question. and `apt-cache policy` please.

Answer (score 0):

The `Unity Tweak Tool` only works on systems running Unity.

If you're running GNOME, then you need to use the `GNOME Tweaks` app...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks`